# Canvas to Save Image and Email

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, imaging

We have a custom product designing tool at "http://dev.ejuicysolutions.com/custom_shirt_designer/". When user will be finished with formatting with text etc... they will click on print button, where they can print but we need to extend functionality from print to "Save Image, as shown in Canvas" and  then email that image. Email can be done but the main problem we are facing is that image is being saved on server but all other formatting like text are not being saved along with. Either script is just placing text etc using styles... on above the canvas... Any idea, how it can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this right, you need to export the canvas content to an image, in the state it is when the user finished his work? There is an export function inside the canvas. canvas.toDataURL(). That way you get a base64 image, default is png format.

Comment: Yes you are right but we have either some confusion or definitely a problem that put text on product is not being retrieved in canvas to be saved along with image. Like if you just visit the above given URL and put text or anything and then click on print and once click on product in popup, file is being saved which can be seen as result at "http://dev.ejuicysolutions.com/custom_shirt_designer/file.png", which shows that formatted text is not retreived in canvas!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the text is just HTML added on top of the canvas, so it wont get encoded with .toDataURL()

If you are using HTML emails you could save the CSS / HTML and then re-apply it on top of the png (set png as background image)

Or alternativly use [canvas text](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-text.php) instead of HTML, then it will be part of the .png